# Check if file exist by API Revit

Tags: c#, security, windows-10, revit-api, file-exists

I have a file that is a Hidden system file - it is placed in the program files folder.

I what to check if it exists, but I'm checking it from a dll run by Revit API.

I do it from computers in my firm but for some users, this doesn't work and I don't know why.
I change this file to be only hidden, but it didn't help,
I change place where this file is created, but it didn't help,
I try to reproduce it and I thought I find a solution. I end up doing this monstrosity

```
    private bool FileExist2(string path)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        if (fi.Exists)
            return true;
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (fi.Attributes == (FileAttributes)(-1))
                {
                }
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but I still have the same tickets coming in. The problem is for windows 10.
Now I don't even know where to search for a solution, or what is the problem.
Is it possible to force one program to have zero access to other folders or files created by other programs?
I only want to know if this file exists.
I know that this file exists because other programs see it.

Help

Comment: To clarify your question, are you trying to check if a file exists using the Revit API?

Comment: @Cflux yes, dll is run by revit